How to perform URL rewrite on HTTPS Loadbalancer for a Backend Bucket?
I'm serving a React APP deployed on a Google Cloud Storage bucket though Cloud CDN. So basically a Backend Bucket behind a Global HTTPS Loadbalancer. I was initially facing the problem that React uses/controlls virtual paths that are exclusive to the browser navigation and does not represent an actual path on the Cloud Storage bucket, and this was causing 404 if a user directly accessed https://example.com/account for example. I fixed this issue by using gsutil web set -m index.html -e index.html gs:// which will serve my index.haml (react) as the 404 page.
The application now works fine, but the problem now is the SEO because robots are getting 404. Serving the index.html is a solution that works only for the browser.
Before using Cloud CDN and HTTPs Loadbalancer I used Nginx container serving the static files, which allowed me to use rewrite to deal with the issue. I had the following Nginx statement:
location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|xml|otf|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  add_header Cache-Control 'max-age=0';
}

I'm probably not the first person going through hosting a SPA application with Google Cloud CDN, so I wonder if I missed anything. I tried creating a rewrite rule on the HTTPS Load Balancer but it doesn't seem to take any effect. This is the routing rules I've tried:
defaultService: projects/example-project/global/backendBuckets/webapp-dev
name: matcher-test
routeRules:
- description: index-rewrite
  matchRules:
  - prefixMatch: /
  priority: 1
  service: projects/example-project/global/backendBuckets/webapp-dev
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathPrefixRewrite: /index.html

So in fewer words, I need all 404 results to be rewritten to index.html with status code 200.

Have you found a solution?

@cyberbudy No, I changed to CloudFlare pages instead.

Hi sharing with you the External Application Load Balancer with Backend Buckets configuration wherein the goal is the URL rewrite. Please focus on the configuration of the backend and Routing rules.
From this example I will use the 2 resources below:
http://IP_ADDRESS/never-fetch/three-cats.jpg
http://IP_ADDRESS/love-to-fetch/two-dogs.jpg
Wherein the “/never-fetch/three-cats.jpg” is stored in /cats (default service) And the “/love-to-fetch/two-dogs.jpg” is stored in /dogs.
Under Backend configuration of the load balancer you need to focus on the “host and path rules”. For host field enter \* for resource “dog” and /love-to-fetch/* in the Paths field.
You can use this command “gcloud compute url-maps describe http-lb” to view the url map and it should look like this:
creationTimestamp: '2020-10-13T11:18:10.561-07:00'
defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendBuckets/cats
fingerprint: MKfYsObzqgw=
hostRules:
- hosts:
  - '*'
  pathMatcher: path-matcher-1
id: '1420501688756228493'
kind: compute#urlMap
name: test-bucket
pathMatchers:
- defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendBuckets/cats
  name: path-matcher-1
  pathRules:
  - paths:
    - /love-to-fetch/*
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendBuckets/dogs
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/urlMaps/http-lb


From this example to rewrite the “/love-to-fetch/” URL to reach “two-dogs.jpg” you can follow this link wherein it focuses on editing host and path rules to rewrite. Below is the screenshot of the steps from the link.
The full details of this information for rewrite can be found on this link and for the load balancer creation with backend buckets is on this link
